# phpstorm javascript how to show object has no function error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phpstorm

for example if we have this code:

```
var a = {
    b:function(){

    }
};
var c = {
    someFunction:function(){

    }
};
a.someFunction();
```

PHPSTORM will not show error for "a.someFunction();"

How can i fix this?

Comment: But `a` has no `someFunction()` -- it only has `b()`. It's `c` that has it...

Comment: yep furthermore if i start typing `a.someF` it will type hint `someFunction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [WEB-1057](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1057). As JS engine doesn't detect object aliasing, completion list contains all existing methods after 'good' variants (list is sorted by relevance).